# Coffeeshop limits Internet connection to 30 minutes -- how does it recognize me if I delete my cookies?

Tags: wireless-networking

I was connected to the Internet in a coffeeshop earlier today, but I was only allowed 30 minutes of access. I tried deleting my cookies after my time was up (though admittedly I didn't delete my *Flash* cookies -- would that have solved the problem?), but the connection still recognized that I'd already used 30 minutes, so I couldn't connect again.

How did the connection recognize me still? The wireless was unprotected (no code or password), it just had a portal you had to pass through upon the initial connection.

I'm not terribly familiar with web development or computer networks, so just trying to get a better idea of what's happening (and possibly to know what to do next time I use up my minutes =)).

Answer (score 10):

I'm guessing it remembered your [MAC address](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address). While it is possible to fake this (and therefore change it regularly to appear to be a different device), most people wouldn't have a clue how to do this and it's therefore as good a method as any to uniquely identify computers on the local domain.

Be warned though: there are techniques for detecting MAC address spoofing, and since it's so obviously a deliberate attempt to get around their conditions of use, you may find yourself at the wrong end of a milk steamer. (Well, the right end of the *steamer*...)

(Also, the most obvious method to detect someone gaming the system is not through magical MAC spoofing detection, but simply through, say, a staff member noticing that you've been tapping away for 45 minutes.)

Comment: lol liked your joke at the end.

Comment: Coffee shop staff can be fearsome when roused. Distract them with complaints about the biscotti not being fruity enough and run the other way.